# Не включается модуль HTTP/2 в Apache 2.4.18 Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, apache-modules, http2

Который раз сталкиваюсь, что в Apache 2.4.18 отсутствует модуль http2, тогда как официальный источник гласит, что модуль доступен с версии 2.4.17 и выше.

При установке выводит сообщение об ошибке:

```
sudo a2enmod http2
ERROR: Module http2 does not exist!
```

Поискал в информацию, [по ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37103927/ubuntu-apache2-module-http2-does-not-exist) на stackoverflow у пользователя Jordi возникла такая же проблема.

Предложенное решение, это обновить apache до 2.4.25 из следующего репозитория:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/apache2
$ sudo apt-key update
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install apache2 -y
$ sudo a2enmod http2
```

И да, это действительно работает, но!
После этого обновления у меня часто возникает "Обнаружена ошибка в системной программе".

Полез в /var/crash, а там данные об ошибке в apache:

```
_usr_sbin_apache2.0.crash
```

[По ссылке](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dOxevE?editors=1000) доступен полный текст ошибки.

А так же полез в логи Apache, там такая картина:

```
[Thu Dec 29 21:37:01.689196 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3518] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Dec 29 21:37:01.878387 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3606] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2j configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Dec 29 21:37:01.878458 2016] [core:notice] [pid 3606] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Dec 29 21:38:33.239717 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3606] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Dec 29 21:38:33.411289 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3817] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2j configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Dec 29 21:38:33.411361 2016] [core:notice] [pid 3817] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Dec 29 21:39:36.094163 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3817] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Dec 29 21:39:52.104885 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4052] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2j configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Dec 29 21:39:52.104953 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4052] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Dec 29 21:39:54.949610 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4052] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Dec 29 21:39:55.218622 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4103] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2j configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Dec 29 21:39:55.218692 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4103] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Посоветуйте, стоит ли таким способом обновить Apache на боевом сервере для включения http2?
Я прочитал, что такого рода ошибки незначительны, и парой даже понижают уровень ошибок в самом Apache, дабы не всплывали такие ошибки. 
И все же, как можно включить http2 без рисков?

SSL сертификаты от Let's Encrypt

Сервер ставил LAMP

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```